# tox error "ImportError: cannot import name suppress"

Tags: tox

When I run tox I am getting below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/tox", line 7, in <module>
    from tox import cmdline
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tox/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pluggy
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .manager import PluginManager, PluginValidationError
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 6, in <module>
    import importlib_metadata
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._compat import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/importlib_metadata/_compat.py", line 21, in <module>
    from contextlib2 import suppress  # noqa
ImportError: cannot import name suppress
```

using Redhat 7.5 and python version 2.7.5

Comment: The python interpreter your tox is installed into  environment is missing the contextlib2 package. I can only guess what the reason is. How did you install tox? Did you try re-installing it?

Comment: Show us your code or [mcve].